# Kali Linux mounting as read-only after suspend

Tags: kali-linux, suspend, sleep, chrome-book

Almost always when I wake my computer up from suspend mode, it says "read only file system" if i try and write to something, and Thunar file manager shows locks on all folders.
I am running Kali Linux off a micro SD card so maybe that could be a problem?
I am on a chromebook.